# How do I get the TTL of a Cassandra column using the Java driver?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, ttl

How to get ttl of a column or a row of a Cassandra row in a table from Java using datastax driver?
Please help.
Also is there a way to update a column of a row using existing ttl through Java code?

Comment: what version of the Java driver?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `ttl()` function from the selectors if you're using the `QueryBuilder`.

For example:

```
selectFrom("mytable").ttl("somecolumn");
```

This is equivalent to the CQL statement:

```
SELECT TTL(somecolumn) FROM mytable
```

Alternatively, you can just use the built-in CQL function `TTL()` in your SELECT statement.

I don't understand the second part of your question so I'm not able to answer it. If you update your original question with additional background information, particularly what you are trying to achieve, I'd be happy to update my answer accordingly. Cheers!